# eclipse how to run a different class

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I want to work on my different class lets say for example house.java but the green play button seems to be locked a program called project.java and only that program. how do I tell Eclipse to run a different classes in the same folder besides the project.java?

Comment: Do these other classes have a main method in them?

Comment: Running program and use shortcut in Eclipse, serious business.

Comment: What's with the smiley face? :)

Answer (score 2):

select your class, then select the small triangle right to the green button, in the dropdown select "Run As" -> "Java Application"

Comment: Also it is required that a main method contains "String[] args" as an argument as written in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114756/eclipse-run-as-has-no-java-application-option-what-exactly-is-needed-to-be?lq=1.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from ways mentioned in the other answers, you can also try this short key.

Short key : Press ALT + SHIFT + X then J

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly left click on your corresponding class code which you want to run and go to **run as-->java application**.hope this will help. :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note that class you want to run should have main method in it.
right click on that class and run as --> java application. it will run :)

Answer (score 0):

`main` method is missing in your script:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```