# Eclipse "Run as" has no "Java Application" option (What exactly is needed to be able to run a class/.java?)

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to run a specific .java file (a class), but Eclipse is not co-operating.

I have tried to follow the instructions here -->
[eclipse how to run a different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898923/eclipse-how-to-run-a-different-class)

... but my "Run As" menu item never contains "Java Project".

I have tried accessing the menu after right-clicking in the .java pane and tab itself, and from the .java name and class name in the Package Explorer, but of course that doesn't make a difference.  The only option I ever get is "Run Configurations".

(and yes, my .java has a "main" method.)

```
import com.jsyn.JSyn;

public class SuperSimpleSounds {

    public static void main() {

[...]
```

What, exactly, is needed to be able to run an individual class (an individual .java file)?

Comment: Are you in the Java or JavaEE or some other perspective? If you don't know what I mean by "perspective", look at the upper right corner of the workspace. There should be a button that says "Java" or "JavaEE". Also, which Eclipse version and bundle are you using?

Comment: I am in the "Java" perspective.  (The other one I see is "Debug".)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add a `String` array argument to the `main` method as expected by the `JVM`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Comment: Wow.  Unbelievable.  I actually did notice this being a difference between the simple program I wanted to run and a more fleshed-out one I had been working one, but I couldn't believe that would matter.  Thank you!  I will have to look up why...

Comment: The why is that Eclipse will not offer a run configuration for the application if the method signature does not match exactly as well as it being a public method :)

Answer (score 1):

Also one trick when you want to open some java classes that you downloaded elsewhere is to create a new Java project. Then, move all your java classes into the src folder of the project. Now you can run with the option of "run as Java Application".

Answer (score 0):

As a minor variation on the [perfect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17114785/3744182) of [Reimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871026/reimeus):

> Add a `String` array argument to the `main` method as expected by the `JVM`
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
> ```

I had been struggling with my a script, when I ran it showed Run Configuration and Fail.
By changing the following:

```
public static void LaunchBrowser () throws InterruptedException {
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
```

it solved the problem.